# Vim - helptags not working for NERDtree

Tags: vim, nerdtree

I downloaded and manually installed NERDTree from
http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1658

```
@hits ➜  .vim rvm:(-ruby-1.9.2)  ls -laR
.:
total 28
drwxr-xr-x  6 hitsu hitsu 4096 2012-02-16 15:21 .
drwxr-xr-x 49 hitsu hitsu 4096 2012-02-27 17:43 ..
drwxrwxr-x  2 hitsu hitsu 4096 2011-12-28 14:18 doc
drwxrwxr-x  2 hitsu hitsu 4096 2011-12-28 14:17 nerdtree_plugin
-rw-rw-r--  1 hitsu hitsu  283 2012-02-07 11:05 .netrwhist
drwxrwxr-x  2 hitsu hitsu 4096 2011-12-28 14:17 plugin
drwxrwxr-x  2 hitsu hitsu 4096 2011-12-28 14:17 syntax

./doc:
total 60
drwxrwxr-x 2 hitsu hitsu  4096 2011-12-28 14:18 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 hitsu hitsu  4096 2012-02-16 15:21 ..
-rw-rw-r-- 1 hitsu hitsu 52744 2011-12-28 14:17 NERD_tree.txt

./nerdtree_plugin:
total 20
drwxrwxr-x 2 hitsu hitsu 4096 2011-12-28 14:17 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 hitsu hitsu 4096 2012-02-16 15:21 ..
-rw-rw-r-- 1 hitsu hitsu 1614 2011-12-28 14:17 exec_menuitem.vim
-rw-rw-r-- 1 hitsu hitsu 8124 2011-12-28 14:17 fs_menu.vim

./plugin:
total 132
drwxrwxr-x 2 hitsu hitsu   4096 2011-12-28 14:17 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 hitsu hitsu   4096 2012-02-16 15:21 ..
-rw-rw-r-- 1 hitsu hitsu 126233 2011-12-28 14:17 NERD_tree.vim

./syntax:
total 12
drwxrwxr-x 2 hitsu hitsu 4096 2011-12-28 14:17 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 hitsu hitsu 4096 2012-02-16 15:21 ..
-rw-rw-r-- 1 hitsu hitsu 3741 2011-12-28 14:17 nerdtree.vim
```

I tried to open the help file for NERDtree in vim.
However when I typed `:helptags` I got the error `E471: Arugment required`

After that I typed `:help NERD_tree.txt` but I got the error `E149: Sorry, can't find help for NERD_tree.txt`

Help instructions are taken from:
http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1658

I know that I can just open NERD_tree.txt in any editor manually (for example vim or Emacs), but I'm just asking out of curiosity.

PS I'm a vim noob. :P

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You have to give `:helptags` the directory where the help file (that you want to be parsed) is. For example:

```
:helptags ~/.vim/doc
```

Comment: @jcollado I'd undelete it, the tip on vundle is valuable ;-)

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem, and resolved it with tips from [another SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5904720/gvim-pathogen-issues):

Apparently you need to `:Helptags` rather than `:helptags`

Comment: I don't know why this solution has -2 (-1 now) because it solved the issue for me...

Comment: `Provided with pathogen.vim is a :Helptags command that does this on every directory in your 'runtimepath'. If you really want to get crazy, you could even invoke Helptags in your vimrc. I don't like to get crazy.` Pathogen, Github

Comment: I tried running :Helptags but it says E492: Not an editor command: Helptags.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, and specifying the directory for `:helptags` didn't resolve the problem.  It didn't return an error, but it also didn't make `:help NERD_tree.txt` work.  The solution that worked for me was installing [pathogen.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen), which is recommended in the [NERD Tree installation directions](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree).  After I did that, `:help NERD_tree.txt` worked.

Answer (score 2):

This is an old thread which I stumbeld upon. I will post my workaround anyways. maybe it can be usefull for another one searching like I did.

I opened a terminal in .vim/pack/bundle/start/nerdtree/doc and then started vim.

```html
:helptags .
```

did the trick for me.