# Vim - :helptags in .vimrc?

Tags: vim

Some time ago, I have a problem with helptags. I posted question on stackoverflow and got answer.

(more info here: [Vim - helptags not working for NERDtree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9468914/vim-helptags-dont-working))

However typing each time I run Vim

```
:helptags ~/.vim/doc
```

is getting tiring.

Is it possible to put above line to .vimrc, so I didnt need to type this every time?

And my second question is: Why I need to type that command over and over again. Why is it happens?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add a shortcut for big commands something like this

```
nmap jj :helptags ~/.vim/doc<CR>
```

From now on if you just type `jj`, `helptags` will be run in normal mode.

**But in this specific case you dont need to do anything!**

You don't need to type it everytime! **Its just a single time process** to generate tags so that when you want some help next time, you can simply type `:help NERDTree` from within `vim` and `vim` will correctly navigate to the exact point in `NERD_tree.txt`

When you download new plugins for vim, they contain their own help files. By saving those help files in the `doc` directory and by running

```
:helptags C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vimfiles\doc " on Windows gVim
:helptags ~/.vim/doc                           " in normal vim
```

we are telling vim "Look! He's a new guy! Add him too, to your help list. I might refer him in future"

Comment: On windows it is `~/vimfiles`. You *must not* put custom plugins into `C:/Program Files (x86)/Vim/vim73`.

Comment: @ZyX I updated my answer with your suggestion. But any specific reason to do so? I mean will the plugins affect in anyway?

Comment: How do you imagine updating vim in case you put those plugins into vim73? If you do the things right, you don’t have permissions to write there anyway (BTW, `~` is not `C/Program Files (x86)/Vim`, it is AFAIK `C:/Users/username` or `C:/Documents and settigs/username`). If `C:/Program files (x86)/Vim` is `vroot`, then `vroot/vim73` is a directory where only files from standart distribution should be put, `vroot/vimfiles` is a place for system-wide installation of third-party plugins.

Comment: If you are the only user no need to put files into `vroot/vimfiles` (and I can’t say that vim installer won’t remove this in case of update).

Answer (score -1):

the only thing I'd add to this is that using:

`nmap jj :helptags ~/.vim/doc<CR>`

as a mapping for helptags ties up `jj` which is a really useful mapping for `<ESC>`

`inoremap jj <ESC>`

which by doing that you don't have to leave the home row to hit `<ESC>` to leave insert mode.

There won't be many times if any at all where you'll actually type `jj` & if you want to type it, just leave a fraction of a second before typing the second `j`